# API for referral leads from the Microsoft Azure Partner Centre

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I want API for referral leads from the Microsoft Partner Centre because it would be better to download customer leads weekly automatically.

I try to find in azure documentation, but I did not get any API apart from documentation.